# Exclude items from a query based on their tags with Symfony/diem and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, diem-cms

In Diem CMS I would like to do a conditional statement that would exclude some articles based on the tag model

Diem documentation gives the following for conditional queries (http://diem-project.org/diem-5-1/doc/en/reference-book/list-widgets)

```
$query = $this->getListQuery('post')
->addWhere('post.name LIKE ?', '%symfony%');
```

Is there a way to exclude some post according to the tags it has?

Here is my new query which seems better (to me at least) but it is still not working.

```
public function executeList()
{
    $query = $this->getListQuery();
    $query->leftJoin('DmTag');
    $query->addWhere('DmTag.name NOT LIKE ?', '%Fichets%');
    $this->articlePager = $this->getPager($query);
    $this->articlePager->setOption('ajax', true);
  }
```

The Diem blog is done according to the Diem tutorial and I use the standard (out of the box so to say) Diem Tag plugin. I did not modify the model nor the name of the Table.

Comment: I did this :     $query = $this->getListQuery('Article')
->addWhere('DmTag.name NOT LIKE ?', 'tagNameThatIwantToExclude'); Because I want to exclude those articles that have this tag but it does not work...

Comment: @Wiglaf: Did you put the `%` wildcards in? - try: `'%tagNameThatIWantToExclude%'`

Comment: @Orbling, I did! Here is my new still not working query... public function executeList()
{
    $query = $this->getListQuery();
    $query->leftJoin('DmTag');
    $query->addWhere('DmTag.name NOT LIKE ?', '%Fichets%');
    $this->articlePager = $this->getPager($query);
    $this->articlePager->setOption('ajax', true);
  }

Comment: @Wiglaf: Try retrieving the generated SQL, to see what is up with it.  `$query->getSqlQuery()` I believe.  Is that join correct?

Comment: @Orbling no your right join is, i believe wrong. Correcting and coming back.

Comment: @Orblling I guess this

$query = $this->getListQuery('Article a');
$query->leftJoin('a.Tags DmTag');

is the equivalent of

$query = $this->getListQuery();
$query->leftJoin('DmTag');

the error is the same, it should be a doctrine short cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working query:

```
public function executeList()
{
    $query = $this->getListQuery('a'); // add an alias
    $query->leftJoin('a.Tags t'); // Join on the DmTag table
    $query->addWhere('t.name NOT LIKE ?', '%Fichets%'); //Exclude the articles with a certain tag
    $this->articlePager = $this->getPager($query);
    $this->articlePager->setOption('ajax', true);
  }
```

Comment: So it was a join problem?  On top of using `NOT LIKE`?

Comment: Yes! I feel a bit dumb but it finally works. I have spend some time but for good: I got the syntax of symfony/diem/doctrine ;)

Comment: Shouldn't worry about it.  Doctrine does take a fair bit of getting used to!